# iOS app Details then List or List then Details

Tags: ios

My apologies as the title is probably a bit confusing. I wasn't able to find anything similar to this in the SE posts or Apples HI Guidelines. I have a scenario in which I have a page that lists different events based upon which roadway is picked.

When the app page first loads it show the the default view (1) which shows the 1st roadway from the list (2) and event/s for it. The list from 2 is only populated with roadways with events so no roadways are listed without events.

To change to a different roadway, the button is clicked and it then shows the list of roadways (2), a different roadway is clicked and it then sends the necessary details to 1 to load the events related to it. Now the events on 1 can be pressed to get complete details on it and where it is on a map.

[image: list]

This is the current process. I got feedback from my boss, not users, that he thinks it should be just the opposite. You should see the list of roadways (2) first and then see 1 after picking a roadway. 2 does have the general *back* button on it if the user decides not to pick to a roadway.

Any suggestions on which approach would be best and why?

Comment: What's the end result of seeing the events? Do users do something with them or add to them?

Comment: They don't. Everything is informational only.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me but your description of the functionality is kind of hard to understand. I still don't fully get what the **purpose** of both of them is

Comment: Which part/s of the description is hard to understand? I can add more details if I know what is opaque.

Comment: This depends on what will the user expect in the first place. If I open a music app I expect to see a list of songs and then select one, not the other way. In your case, what are the reasons why you think the Single view should be opened at first?

Comment: I really don't have a preference. I just went with 1 -> 2 based upon prior experience, primarily web. You really brought up a good point about the music app though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

- Single view
- List view

Which one to show on start will depend on the user expectation and the context of the app. But in most contexts if I open an app for the first time I would expect a *List view* rather than a *Single view*.

If the app is opened for the first time it might make sense to show the *List view*. Then the user Selects an element and the app goes to its *Single view*.

If the app is closed and opened again there are two scenarios:

- **The process finished**: imagine a song playing in a music app, if the song finished playing and stopped then I would expect to see the *List view*
- **The process is running**: in the music app example, I would expect to see the current song in some degree (both views could be mixed with a minimum single view, though).

The "process" will depend on the app and the context. If it is a reading app, where there are several books, the process might last days or weeks.

Comment: This is great. Appreciate the details.

Comment: I'm glad if it could help :)